Manhwa/manhua in which a bunch of people were teleported by train to a strange city of monsters
Does anyone know a manhwa/manhua where the main character teleports to a strange city of monsters by sitting on a train? He has to go on various quests, like surviving at the station itself (that was the first quest), and surviving in a building with killer monsters (that was the second or third quest), etc. Also, there was a girl who was special (she was not hunted/targeted).
It's been ~2 years since I read it on Mangaowl. It was colored and took place in the modern world (although a parallel dimension... that's where the train took these randoms). It was electric, i.e. a subway setting.
It's horror with monsters, like Slenderman, etc. I guess it was a Korean comic, since a bunch of people were teleported (by train) to that parallel dimension.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it black-and-white or colour?  Did it take place in a modern world or a older one?  (Was it an electric train or a steam train?)

It's been ~2 yr I read it on mangaowl ....it was colored ....it took place in modern world(altho parallel dimension...that's where train took these random s)....it was electric ig subway setting

Maybe not https://myanimelist.net/manga/146817/Meikyuu_Metro__Mezametara_Saikyoushoku_Datta_node_Shimarisu_wo_Tsurete_Shinsekai_wo_Aruku

Is it a game system kinda thing or no

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Wrong answers are an excellent chance to [edit] new details into the question, e.g. "I know it isn't Last Train To Tolkien because elves didn't factor into the storyline, and the main character was middle-aged, not a teenager."

https://mangatoto.com/chapter/1138709 found it tysm guys

@SuperxShm: Post that as an answer! Write it up as if you were answering someone else's question (provide a good summary, why it matches, etc). As a self-answer, you can't accept it for 48 hours after you asked it, but you will be able to click on that checkmark.

@SuperxShm: I've posted an answer, but if you want to post your own, I can retract mine. You can feel free to borrow any or all of it, since it's largely cut and paste.

Just in case the querent does not return, they determined the work to be Death Field


Slender Man, Mothman, the Butcher, Cecil Hotel, the Slit-Mouthed Woman, Hanako of the Toilet, the Non-existent Stairs of the 13th floor, the Cat-faced Granny, Bus 330, Jack The Ripper… Welcome, travelers, to the world of 999 strange tales - the spirit world.

The protagonist, Ji Ling, is a horror author who believes that he is in a manhua.

And he does meet a mysterious girl in the first chapter, after suddenly finding himself on a deserted train.


Might it be Omniscient Reader (aka Omniscient Reader's Viewpoint)?


‘Omniscient Reader’ focuses on Kim Dokja, a lonely 28-year-old office worker in Korea who reads web novels as a hobby. On a subway ride home, the web novel Dokja had been reading for the past decade finally comes to an end. The in-story web novel, “Three Ways to Survive the Apocalypse (TWSA)” written by an anonymous writer tls123, ended with over 3,000 chapters, with Dokja as the only reader of the web novel—which also meant that only he knew how the story would end. Upon finishing the novel, the anonymous author, tls123, reaches out to Dokja, saying that TWSA would become paid content at 7 pm. Coincidentally, the subway Dokja was riding was attacked at 7 pm. When a dokkaebi, or Korean goblin, gives a quest scenario from TWSA, Dokja realizes that the beloved novel he’s read for the past decade has turned into reality. When the real world is plunged into the premise of Ways of Survival, Kim Dokja’s knowledge of the novel becomes vital to his survival. He allies with the protagonist of the novel Yoo Joong-hyuk to change the original story of the novel.

The Wikipedia article mentions a female co-worker who might be the woman you are thinking of.

Yoo Sangah (유상아; 劉尚雅; Yu Sanga) is Kim Dokja's co-worker who he considers to be an ideal protagonist. She is on the subway with Kim Dokja as the events of the novel start to unfold, and she becomes a powerful figure in her own right despite not appearing in nor having knowledge of the original novel.


Was thinking this too but Dojka doesn't tp to a alt universe iirc
